# Unwanted Padding/Margin at the beginning of a custom toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar, androiddesignsupport

I have a fairly complex custom toolbar (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) that’s created via xml:

(e.g. dumbed down example)

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
   <ImageView/>
   <TextView/>
 </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

This works well except I end up with margin/padding to the left of my ImageView. `toolbar.setNavigationIcon(null)` doesn’t change anything. Changing the padding and margin doesn't seem to do anything. I’m not sure where that’s coming from.

How do I get rid of this?

[image: toolbar with spacing example]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add `app:contentInsetStart="0dp"` to your `Toolbar` if you want it to be flush with the starting (left in LTR) edge. There's also `contentInsetEnd` for the other side.

Comment: For future readers, note this is `app:contentInsetStart` not `android:contentInsetStart`. Made that mistake :)

Comment: Well, if you use the Framework Toolbar, you'd need the android version, but who would do that? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Programmatically you can set the padding and Insets value to 0.

```
toolbar.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
toolbar.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0,0);
```